# Get Image Dimensions Given Ratio

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a django template filter that can output image dimensions for `sorl thumbnail`.
The thing with sorl is it expects dimensions like `800x1000` for pixels but I've come to work with images that dimensions might vary and for places like a caurosel it's something you want to show as much as possible with as little cropping as possible. The cropping becomes useful to avoid images ratio being so different that either one image looks larger than another as the caurosel scrolls or css forces it too look squished to fix a set maximum height.
So let's say a desires ratio of `2:1` is desired for the caurosel that being width being twice as large as the height.

I've tried writing a template filter that would get the image and the ratio and output the pixel dimensions that's the maximum allowed that meets the required aspect ratio.

```
def image_dimensions(image, ratio):
    width = image.width
    height = image.height

    if 'x' in ratio:
        return ratio
    elif ratio == '1:1':
        if width > height:
            return '{0}x{0}'.format(height)
        else:
            return '{0}x{0}'.format(width)
    elif ':' in ratio:
        x, y = [int(x) for x in ratio.split(':')] #Example 2:1
        if x > y:
            if height/x < width:
                return '{0}x{1}'.format(width, height/x)
            else:
                return '{0}x{1}'.format(width/x, height)
```

this is what I have so far and I can tell of the bat it won't fit well into all the possible solutions like `4:3` which I'm guessing I will need to encounter later.

If you know of a short snippet that can do this I'll appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked up openCV library for image processing? It has the tools for resizing as well. 
Also the last part with `height/x` and `width/x` doesn't seem right. check it. You already have height and width parameters with pixels, make your ratio a float (2 for 2:1, 1.333 for 4:3) then use that ratio to calculate corresponding width required for the height.

```
ratio=x/y 
req_width=int(height*ratio)
if(req_width<width):
   return '{0}x{1}'.format(req_width,height)
else:
   return '{0}x{1}'.format(width,int(width/ratio))
```

Edit: And you don't have to check for 1:1

```
def ImgDim(width,height,ratio):
 #ratio is width:height
 if 'x' in ratio:
   return ratio
 x,y=ratio.split(":")
 x,y=int(x),int(y)
 ratio=x/y 
 req_width=int(height*ratio)
 if(req_width<width):
   return '{0}x{1}'.format(req_width,height)
 else:
   return '{0}x{1}'.format(width,int(width/ratio))
#TESTING
print(ImgDim(1500,1000,"2:1"))
#will print 1500x750
```

Comment: Close but this isn't correct `In [3]: image_dimensions(1500, 1000, '2:1')                                                                                         
Out[3]: '1500x500'
` 1500 isn't twice the size of 500

Comment: sorry the last part should have been `int(width/ratio)` I have corrected it in the code.